# Getting html data from wikipedia api using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to log data to my console but I keep getting an error, what might be wrong with the code? Actually trying to display the html content on a page. Here is my snippet

```
$(function () {
$.ajax({
url: '//en.wikipedia.org//w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=pizza&prop=text&section=0&contentmodel=wikitext&formatversion=2',
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function (data) {
console.log(data);
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: "I keep getting an error" — What error?!

Comment: well you have format is json and you are making a jsonp call...

Comment: @epascarello — That URL returns JSONP when you add a callback (which jQuery does when you say jsonp)

Comment: I get a net:: ERR_FILE NOT error message on my chrome console

Comment: @Quentin a net::ERR FILE NOT FOUND error message, what might be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

> net::ERR FILE NOT FOUND error message

Your URL starts with `//` so it uses whatever scheme the URL of the HTML document the JS is running in uses.

If you load the HTML document over HTTP then you try to access Wikipedia over HTTP.

If you load the HTML document over HTTPS then you try to access Wikipedia over HTTPS.

If you load the HTML from a local file, then you try to access Wikipedia from your own hard disk … where it doesn't exist.

Use an absolute URL or, better, test your webpages on a web server.